# Blender 2.77 Bone Constraint

Tags: constraints

I have a question about 2.77 blender, I cannot find the bone constraint so I cannot have one object track another. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Select a bone, switch to Pose mode and you will find all the bone constraints in the properties window.

[image]